# Counting Characters in a String in armV7

Tags: assembly, arm, raspberry-pi3

My program is supposed to ask for a single line of user input and then print out the number of characters in the string. As of now it is telling me there are 104 characters when I input hello followed by a segmentation fault.

Here is my code:

```
userInput:
    .asciz "\nEnter a string: " 

TemptRet:
    .word 10


inputBuffer:    
    .skip   11

countMessage:
    .STRING "There are %d characters in: \"%s\".\n"



.text
.global main


main:
    LDR R0, =courseStr
    BL puts

countString:
    LDR R0, =userInput
    BL printf

    LDR R0, =TemptRet
    BL scanf

getLine:
    MOV R2, R0
    BL getchar


    LDR R2, =inputBuffer
    MOV R1, R0
    LDR R0, =countMessage
    BL printf
```

Comment: You don't return from main, just let execution fall off into nowhere, so it'll definitely segfault there if not sooner.  `getchar` returns the character (i.e. an ASCII code) in R0, and you're printing that as an integer.  `104 = 'h'`.  Run your program under a debugger.  You don't have any loops or any functions that input more than 1 char - hopefully you know that and weren't expecting this to actually work?

Comment: I suggest making your sample self-contained - there are references to undefined symbols (`courseStr`).

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions.

Your use of `scanf` to read in a string is going to stop at the first space in your input.  Instead you can use `fgets` which looks a bit more complicated but with understanding the ARM procedure calling convention is quite easy.

Second, move your `.data` section to the end and start with `push {ip, lr}` so your routine can end with `pop {ip, pc}`.

Consider using comments in your assembly to understand what each line is doing.  Writing in a high-level language without comments is bad enough, in assembly it is even easier to forget what you were doing.

There are several key sections to the code below:

- Prompting the user to enter a string
- Setting up r0, r1, and r2 to utilize `fgets` (pay particular attention to the use of loading the value of `FILE* stdin` into r2)
- Calculating the length of the string and chopping off the newline
- Printing the result

`input.s`:

```
.global main

main:
    push {ip, lr}

    ldr r0,=prompt // r0 <- prompt*
    bl printf

    ldr r0,=buffer // r0 <- buffer*
    mov r1,#buflen // r1 <- buflen
    ldr r2,=stdin
    ldr r2,[r2]    // r2 <- STDIN
    bl  fgets      // fgets(buffer, buflen, STDIN)
    bl strlen      // r0 <- strlen(buffer)
    mov r1,r0      // r1 <- strlen(buffer)
    sub r1,#1      // r1 <- r1 - 1

    ldr r0,=output // r0 <- output*
    ldr r2,=buffer // r2 <- buffer*
    mov r4,#0
    str r4,[r2,r1] // r4(NULL) -> buffer + strlen
    bl printf

    pop {ip, pc}

.data
prompt:.asciz "Enter a string: "
output:.asciz "There are %d characters in: \"%s\".\n"
buffer:.space 128
buflen=.-buffer
```

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ gcc input.s -o input
```

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./input
Enter a string: this is a string of moderate length
There are 35 characters in: "this is a string of moderate length".
```

Good luck.

Comment: Note that `fgets` returns NULL on error or when no chars have been read.  But yes, otherwise it does return the pointer in `r0`, which is also the first arg-passing register in ARM's calling convention (you should comment on that; it's not because `r0` is unmodified from passing `buffer` to fgets).  So if you don't care about `strlen` segfaulting on bad/empty input, that works.  Unfortunately `fgets` doesn't bother to return how many bytes it read, throwing away the work it did in searching for a newline in the stdio input buffer.

Comment: @PeterCordes great feedback there and worth me going back and updating to check the return value of `fgets`!

Comment: While you're at it, loading `buflen` from memory is silly; it can be an assemble-time constant you define right after `buffer` with `.equ` or `buflen = . - buffer`.  If you actually just `strlen` your initially-zero buffer instead of the `fgets` return value, that would silently handle the error/empty case for free.  Toy programs in asm usually don't bother with error checking; especially if you're making system calls directly  `strace ./a.out` can do that from outside your process.