# GAS Assembler - Fgets function SegFaults

Tags: assembly, arm, fgets, gnu-assembler

This simple program segfaults when I try to use fgets. I have tried using read function instead with

```
       ldr r1, =input_string
       mov r3, #80
       mov r0, #0
       bl read
```

but this fails with

> read(0, 0x21044, 3201061676)  = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)

So I am attempting to use fgets. It seems there is something wrong with my string buffer?

```
.data

.balign 4
message1:       .asciz "Please type a string: \n"

.balign 4
input_string:
        .asciz ""
        .zero 80

return: .word 0

.text
.global main

main:
        push {lr}
        ldr r0, =message1
        bl printf
        mov r0, #0
        bl fflush

        ldr r0, =input_string
        mov r1, #80
        mov r2, #0

        bl fgets

        mov r0, r1
        bl printf

        pop {lr}
        bx lr
.end


.global printf
.global read
.global fgets
```

EDIT:
I attempted to use stdin as per the example given in the comments, but this fails to compile saying:
Error: immediate expression requires a # prefix -- `mov r2,=stdin'

> ```
>     ldr r0, =input_string
>     mov r1,   #80
>     mov r2,   =stdin
>     ldr r2,   [r2]
> ```

There doesn't seem to be a predefined macro for "stdin" like in C, so how do I tell it to use stdin?

Comment: What do you expect when you pass a `NULL` pointer for the `FILE*` 3rd arg of `fgets`?  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html  `read` takes a Unix file descriptor (as the first arg), `fgets` takes a stdio `FILE*` as the last arg.

Comment: [Counting Characters in a String in armV7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61847657) shows how to use `fgets`.

Comment: Just noticed that your `read` call is passing the length in `r3`, a non-existant 4th arg, rather than `r2` (the 3rd arg).  Also, in asm it's fairly common to inline the `svc` system-call instruction instead of calling the libc wrapper.  (With the call number in R7, IIRC).  But you don't need to do that.

Comment: I passed the string buffer as arg1, number of bites as arg2, and what I thought was stdin, but the example you linked to seems to show a predefined stdin. But when I try it it doesn't work. 

        ldr r0, =input_string
        mov r1, #80
        mov r2, =stdin
        ldr r2, [r2]

Comment: Yes, `FILE *stdin` is a global pointer variable initialized by the libc startup code to point at a `FILE` struct.  I'd have expected that to work, at least if you did `ldr r2, =stdin` not `mov`.  Look at C compiler output (https://godbolt.org/)

Comment: Thanks! I figured out I was using the wrong instruction (mov instead of ldr), just before I looked at your comment. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
   ldr r0,=input_string
   mov r1,#80
   ldr r2,=stdin
   ldr r2,[r2]
   bl fgets
```

The answer is to use LDR and stdin